# Marsa Alam - Are there any buses?

Tags: buses, egypt

I am going to Marsa Alam in Egypt next month and would like to know how to get around without taking a taxi. Are there any buses there? Is there a timetable available online? I could not find one.

Comment: A quick Google search gives [this](https://www.ask-aladdin.com/egypt-transport-system/bus-timetables) and [this](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Cairo/Marsa-Alam#r/Bus/s/0).

Comment: Shared taxis/minibuses have been used outside of Europe long before "ride-sharing" became popular. Typically they run fixed routes and depart when full. See [Service Taxi](https://www.roughguides.com/egypt/getting-around/#by-service-taxi). I did not use them in Egypt, but in Morocco it was worth buying the whole front passenger seat, especially for a long distance trip (a normally 4-passenger car would be carrying 6 passengers, 2 in front and 4 in back). In India they could be so full it might be hard to tell who was doing the driving :)